# what are the difference of between glGenBuffers and glGenFramebuffers and glGenRenderbuffers

Tags: iphone, ios5, opengl-es-2.0

the description of them in http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/ are almost same. The only difference is the name

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There's a difference between plain old buffers and frame buffers and render buffers ([used in offscreen rendering](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html#renderbuffer)).  The overall functionality of those "glGen_*_*" functions is the same, but they just generate different kinds of buffer object names.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I have one more question. Which situation do  I need to use them? For example when using compileShaders. am i correct?

Comment: @Michael thanks for pointing out they're different. Care to share your knowledge about **how** they're different?

Comment: This answer is enlightening. Thanks @Michael!

Answer (score 8):

**glGenBuffers** creates regular buffers for vertex data, etc.

**glGenFrameBuffers** creates a framebuffer object primarily used as render targets for offscreen rendering.

**glGenRenderBuffers** creates a renderbuffer object that are specifically used with framebuffer objects for any depth-testing required.